# Converting UWP XAML animation to C#

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a working XAML animation for animating an odometer-like digit.  I need to make six almost identical, but different, versions of this animation.  So far as I can tell there is not a nice way to reuse animation XAML in this way, so to keep the code DRY I turn to a programatic creation of the animation.

In trying to convert this XAML animation to C# I've run into an issue where my target can't be found:

> No installed components were detected.\r\n\r\nCannot resolve TargetName Digit1.

If I call `Storyboard.SetTarget()` instead of `Storyboard.SetTargetName()` I no longer get this exception but still nothing happens on the screen.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in this translation?

XAML:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="OdometerMoveUpDistance">-101</x:Double>

        <Storyboard x:Name="OdometerUpStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Digit1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{StaticResource OdometerMoveUpDistance}" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Name="Odometer" Width="100" Height="100">
        <TextBlock x:Name="Digit1" FontSize="100" Text="8">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform><CompositeTransform /></TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>

</Page>
```

C#:

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames digitUp = CreateOdometerdigitAnim(this.Digit1, 0, -101);

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(digitUp);
    storyboard.Begin(); // Exception happens on this line
}

private DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames CreateOdometerdigitAnim(TextBlock digit, double startPos, double endPos)
{
    var start = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
    start.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0));
    start.Value = startPos;

    var end = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
    end.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
    end.Value = endPos;

    var anim = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    anim.KeyFrames.Add(start);
    anim.KeyFrames.Add(end);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)");
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim, digit.Name);

    /* Using SetTarget instead of SetTargetName throws no exception but still does not animate */
    // Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, digit);

    return anim;
}
```

Comment: This can be a PITA.  Normally, what I do if I need to interact with the animation in codebehind, is I just define it as a resource in xaml, then get the animation from resources in my codebehind.  Saves the trouble of converting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I call Storyboard.SetTarget() instead of Storyboard.SetTargetName() I no longer get this exception but still nothing happens on the screen.

You need to give a `CompositeTransform` object to `Digit1.RenderTransform`. You can do it either in XAML or in code-behind:

If in XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Digit1" FontSize="100" Text="8">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

If in Code-Behind, add the codes before `storyboard.Begin()` like below:

```
Digit1.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
...
storyboard.Begin();
```

> In trying to convert this XAML animation to C# I've run into an issue where my target can't be found:
>
> No installed components were detected.\r\n\r\nCannot resolve TargetName Digit1.

I can reproduce the problem with your codes. I tried it with a XAML defined StoryBoard+Animation, everything works fine. Need some confirmations through internal channel later.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  My apologies, it turns out that I did have the `CompositeTransform` in my XAML because Blend added it, but I did not know what its purpose was and mistakenly removed it for brevity in my example.  I'm so glad to hear that my issue is reproducable, any information you could gather about the root cause would be immensely helpful!

Comment: `Storyboard.SetTarget()` should work fine now. For `Storyboard.SetTargetName` I need some confirmation through internal channel, I'll let you know if I have any response.